# Is there a neat way to say the hour equivalent of 'today' or 'this week'?

Tags: single-word-requests, time

I'm writing an online game, and I want to tell users what their highscore is since the beginning of the hour. But I don't want to say something wordy like:

> Your highscore since the beginning of the hour is...

At the moment I've got:

> Your highscore this hour is...

I have 'today' and 'this week' for the other timeframes, but it still feels very unnatural.

Is there any pithy phrase I'm overlooking?

Many thanks!

Comment: @All **Write an answer, not a comment.**

Comment: @AndrewLeach You might want to weigh in on this at ELL where serial offenders abound. The mods do nothing about it.

Answer (score 3):

"This hour" is used, especially to describe the current period of hourly rolling news programmes. It's not unknown in the context of an hourly period which resets at xx:00 (the "top of the hour").

> Joining us live now from Edinburgh, Scotland, is NBC News correspondent Kelly Cobiella.
>
> Kelly, thanks for joining us this hour.
>
> — *[Alex Wagner Tonight](https://www.msnbc.com/transcripts/alex-wagner-tonight/transcript-alex-wagner-tonight-9-8-22-n1298763),* NBC 8 September 2022

I'm sure there are better ways of expressing the period in British English.

Comment: That's very interesting - thank you! Yes I don't think we have that in British English (yet!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same phrasing for all the high scores:

> Your highscore of the week is ...
> Your highscore of the day is ...
> Your highscore of the hour is ...

Typical other uses of the phrasing are

> Dish of the day
> Word of the day
> Highlight of the week

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[to date](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/to-date)

> up to the present time:

I prefer:

**Your topscore to date!**